# Bluetooth Audio not working after reconnection

Tags: sound, 22.04, bluetooth

I have an Ubuntu 22.04 system. I have paired a cheap pair of headphones to the laptop and they work great on the first connection.

Once I disconnect them and reconnect them, I get no new audio device to select until I disconnect and reconnect the bluetooth connection through settings, at which point I get this:

```
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop wireplumber[5839]: [66B blob data]
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop kernel: input: BE1032 (AVRCP) as /devices/virtual/input/input41
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop systemd-logind[3675]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event24 (BE1032 (AVRCP))
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device BE1032 (AVRCP) (/dev/input/event24)
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (**) BE1032 (AVRCP): Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'BE1032 (AVRCP)'
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/input/event24 13:88 fd 105 paused 0
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (**) BE1032 (AVRCP): always reports core events
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event24"
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (II) event24 - BE1032 (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (II) event24 - BE1032 (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (II) event24 - BE1032 (AVRCP): device removed
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/virtual/input/input41/event24"
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "BE1032 (AVRCP)" (type: KEYBOARD, id 22)
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (**) Option "xkb_layout" "gb"
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (WW) Option "xkb_variant" requires a string value
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (WW) Option "xkb_options" requires a string value
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (II) event24 - BE1032 (AVRCP): is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop /usr/libexec/gdm-x-session[5910]: (II) event24 - BE1032 (AVRCP): device is a keyboard
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop wireplumber[5839]: RFCOMM receive command but modem not available: AT+CCWA=1
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop wireplumber[5839]: RFCOMM receive command but modem not available: AT+NREC=0
Mar 15 12:01:40 my-laptop wireplumber[5839]: RFCOMM receive command but modem not available: AT+CGMI?
Mar 15 12:01:42 my-laptop bluetoothd[3636]: /org/bluez/hci0/dev_6E_E8_A1_6D_A8_F5/sep1/fd7: fd(42) ready
Mar 15 12:01:42 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: clutter_actor_remove_child: assertion 'child->priv->parent == self' failed
Mar 15 12:01:42 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: clutter_actor_insert_child_above: assertion 'child->priv->parent == NULL' failed
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gsd-media-keys[6734]: Unable to get default sink
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: clutter_actor_remove_child: assertion 'child->priv->parent == self' failed
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: clutter_actor_insert_child_above: assertion 'child->priv->parent == NULL' failed
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gsd-media-keys[6734]: Sync_devices: Failed to match stream id: 703, description: 'Handsfree', origin: 'BE1032'
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gsd-media-keys[6734]: Sync_devices: Failed to match stream id: 704, description: 'Handsfree', origin: 'BE1032'
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gjs[6816]: Sync_devices: Failed to match stream id: 703, description: 'Handsfree', origin: 'BE1032'
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gjs[6816]: Sync_devices: Failed to match stream id: 704, description: 'Handsfree', origin: 'BE1032'
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: clutter_actor_remove_child: assertion 'child->priv->parent == self' failed
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: clutter_actor_insert_child_above: assertion 'child->priv->parent == NULL' failed
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: Sync_devices: Failed to match stream id: 85, description: 'Handsfree', origin: 'BE1032'
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: clutter_actor_remove_child: assertion 'child->priv->parent == self' failed
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: clutter_actor_insert_child_above: assertion 'child->priv->parent == NULL' failed
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: Sync_devices: Failed to match stream id: 86, description: 'Handsfree', origin: 'BE1032'
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gsd-media-keys[6734]: gvc_mixer_ui_device_get_id: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_UI_DEVICE (device)' failed
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gjs[6816]: gvc_mixer_ui_device_get_id: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_UI_DEVICE (device)' failed
Mar 15 12:01:45 my-laptop gnome-shell[622118]: gvc_mixer_ui_device_get_id: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_UI_DEVICE (device)' failed
```